# Delete brackets from column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tokenize

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['Severe weather Not Severe weather kind of severe weather]})
```

I tokenized this dataframe:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
df['column1'] = df['column1'].apply(lambda x: word_tokenize(x))
```

The output is enclosed inside brackets:

```
column1
0   [Severe, weather, Not, Severe, weather, kind, of, severe, weather]
```

I want  the have the output without brackets:

```
column1
0 Severe, weather, Not, Severe, weather, kind, of, severe, weather
```

What I have tried:

```
def delete_brackets(x):
    for i in x:
        if i == '[' or i == ']':
            x.remove(i)
    return x
df=delete_brackets(df)
```

and

```
def remove_brackets(x):
    return x.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
df=remove_brackets(df)
```

Still getting the output inside brackets

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: It's just how python lists are represented when printed, there are no brackets there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['column1'] = df['column1'].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(map(str, word_tokenize(x))))
```

Output:

```
>>> print(df.to_string())
                                                            column1
0  Severe, weather, Not, Severe, weather, kind, of, severe, weather
```

The [`word_tokenize()` function](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize) returns a list of tokens that you need to cast to `str` (this is done with `map(str, word_tokenize(x))`) and then you can join the strings with a comma and space.

Answer (score 0):

you missed .str

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.replace("[","", regex=True).replace("]","", regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also `lstrip`/`rstrip`:

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.lstrip('[').str.rstrip(']')
```